# Конвертация кода C# => VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

День добрый. Переписывал библиотеку с C# на более удобный для себя VB.NET и не смог разобраться как написать два куска кода.

Код 1.

```
throw new RucaptchaErrorException((RucaptchaError)Enum.Parse(typeof(RucaptchaError),
str.Substring(6)));
```

Попытка получить хоть какой то код через декомпилятор выглядит так:

```
Throw New RucaptchaErrorException(DirectCast(Enum.Parse(GetType(RucaptchaError), Str.Substring(6)), 
RucaptchaError))
```

Код 2.

```
public object Clone()
{
    var paramsContainer = new ParamsContainer();
    foreach (var obj in from object index in Params.Keys select (Param) Params[index])
        paramsContainer.Params.Add(obj.Key, obj);
    return paramsContainer;
}
```

При попытке конвертнуть этот метод, у декомпилятора вообще снесло крышу и получившийся кусок даже не стоит приводить.

Прошу помощи.

Comment: А каким декомпилятором вы пользуетесь? У меня ILSpy вполне справлялся, вроде (но это было давно).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Код 1:

```
Throw New RucaptchaErrorException(DirectCast(System.Enum.Parse(GetType(RucaptchaError), str.Substring(6)), RucaptchaError))
```

Код 2:

```
Option Infer On

Public Function Clone() As Object
    Dim paramsContainer = New ParamsContainer()
    For Each obj In
        From index As Object In Params.Keys
        Select CType(Params(index), Param)
        paramsContainer.Params.Add(obj.Key, obj)
    Next obj
    Return paramsContainer
End Function
```

p.s. могут быть ошибки, использовал конвертер: http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Free_Edition_Downloads/Instant%20VB%20(Free%20Edition)%20Setup.exe

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!